# blackberry widget not respecting jquery hide/show

Tags: jquery, blackberry, widget, blackberry-os6

I am trying to use jquery with blackberry widget on a OS6 device.
Widget compiler does not seem to recognize .hide() and .show() (css display properties)
Is there a workaround to this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a").click( function() 
    { 
        ShowAPage(this.id)  
    });

    function ShowAPage(pageToShow){     
        $("div.page").hide();
        targetPage =  "div#" + pageToShow ;     
        $(targetPage).show();           
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.page").css("display", "none"); //This hides
```

and:

```
$(targetPage).css("display", "block"); //This shows
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thanks, i am trying it, but my guess that it won't work either... Jquery Mobile is able to do it. I wonder what technique they use.

Comment: No it does not work. There seem to be issues with Blackberry tool